# Programmatically lock a window in position in OSX

Tags: macos

I'd like to be able to have an application permanently positioned in a specific place, and prevent other windows from overlapping it.

In Windows, this would be called an *Application Desktop Toolbar* (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I have never seen an app with this in OSX (although I have only been using it full-time for a year), so perhaps this is not possible (/allowed).

If this is possible, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make window not movable:

```
NSApp.mainWindow.movable = NO;
```

And to make it over other windows:

```
NSApp.mainWindow.level = NSScreenSaverWindowLevel;
```

Comment: This definitely answers my question as I asked it although I unfortunately asked slightly the wrong question.